# EC2 refuses to connect to EFS in same availability zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a EFS on my private subnet in us-east-1a az. Then I tried creating a EC2 instance in my public subnet in us-east-1a az but I get the following error when trying to attach EFS on launch wizard:

The specified file system does not have a mount target in the Availability Zone of the selected subnet. Choose a different subnet.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to mount your EFS on your instance, you need to create a mount target in the the same availability zone of which your EC2 instance is located (1).

(1) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/manage-fs-access.html

Answer (score 0):

Since the subnets were different, I had to create the instance first with a sg and then add the sg of the instance in the ingress of the EFS's sg.

After that I manually attached the EFS to the EC2 with the commands.

It looks like it is not possible to attach an EFS in a different subnet from the AWS EC2 Launch Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

for new users having the same issue
you need to create a mount target before, then you can attach an EC2 instance to an EFS
[image]